# How do I launch a Jquery event on an HTML website using Java and Eclipse?

Tags: java, jquery, html

I am trying to simulate a button click on my school portal's login page. However, when I look into code, I see only name and ID and then an "event" button. The "event" button shows a redirection to the jquery file that redirects the user to a specfic link. I attached some parts of a code.

How can I launch that event inside my code to simulate the button click and get automatically redirected.

P.S. I would be constantly checking for responses, so if there is not enough information, please tell me, so I can create a better question.

[This is a picture of a Login button code:

`<input id="LoginButton" style="visibility: visible" type="button" value="Log In">`event

I need these actions to be performed directly from my application. (This is located in the index.php folder

```
function gotologinreminder() {
    top.location = '/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoginReminder';
};
$("#LoginButton").click(function () {
    $("#msgdisplay").hide();
    $("#imgwait").show();
    if ($("#Pin").val() == "" || $("#Password").val() == "") {
        $("#imgwait").hide();
        $("#msg1").show();
        return;
    };
    $("#loginform").submit();
});
$("#loginform").ajaxForm(function (retval) {
    if (retval.valid == "0") {
        $("#imgwait").hide();
        $("#msgmessage").html(retval.msg);
        $("#msgdisplay").show();
        $("#Pin").val("");
        $("#Password").val("");
        $("#Pin").focus();
    } else {
        $(window).off('resize.rightcolumn');
        top.location = '/novi/StudentPortal/Home/PortalMainPage';
    };
});
function clearmessages() {
    $("#msgdisplay").hide();
    $("#msg1").hide();
};
```

Thank you,

Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to login through Java code to a website, which has code written in JavaScript. In this case, it would be better to have a look to the network requests that occur as you make the login in the [Network tab in the developer console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm5oV.png) Specially have a look at those requests made with a POST method, for this means your browser is sending info to the website. I also suggest using the Jsoup library, because it facilitates this type of requests.

Edit 1: I have made an [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNGRT.jpg) of screen captures to help you understand.
The last image is of the code you would put in a Java Class to make the same login. (I blurred out some info but you will understand)

After getting the document you can then scrape the site using Jsoup as well, [here is the documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Note: What the JS code you have shows is nothing more than a validation and the corresponding changes in the UI of the website, for example, checking if either the user or password are empty and then showing an error on the website. The actual form submit function (retval) is not in the code you show (at least as far as I can tell).

To pass the login cookie with Jsoup you would do this:

```
 Document profilePicDocument = Jsoup.connect(This is the new URL you want to access)
            .cookies(secondLoginPost.cookies()) //secondLoginPost is the last POST request
            .get();
```

Comment: I have been using the JSoup library to parse the website. However, I the "event" that is happening is located in a different file. Also, when I try to directly login, it gives me an instant timeout (I think it happens for all school portals). So I decided to complitely simulate user's behavior to at least start developing my project beyond login.

P.S. This is a website I am trying to login into. https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/

Comment: The URL you need is this:https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/Login. The user is "Pin", the password is sent as "Password". I could try help you but I would need a valid login. Anyway, I don't think getting the UI simulation is a necessary thing.

Comment: Once you have sent the POST you will most likely be given a cookie by the server to be able to keep logged in. This cookie you need to pass along every other request you make. After you are logged in the JS code sends you to /novi/StudentPortal/Home/PortalMainPage. But to be logged in you need to pass the cookie

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I would try to implement that and comment if I don't understand something. Thank you!

Comment: I added an explanation for the cookies to my original answer. Do have in mind there is another hidden field called "districtid" which is by default empty. I do not know if that is always the case.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got it to work. Now I just need to get all the info, but that is easy with Jsoup. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just web scraping, @Jacob's answer with JSoup is probably the way to go. If you're looking for something like automated UI testing, you could also consider Selenium Web Driver -- which is Java based.